# using Gadlfy.jl and AlgebraOfGraphics.jl within same notebook causes MethodError

Tags: namespaces, julia, gadfly

I am making a Pluto notebook where I create the same simple plot with several plotting libraries. Since plotting libraries might define functions with the same name I work like this:

```
using AlgebraOfGraphics, RDatasets, CairoMakie
const AoG = AlgebraOfGraphics

iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

iris_frequency = AoG.data(iris) *
    AoG.mapping(:PetalLength, :PetalWidth) *
    AoG.mapping(color = :Species) 
AoG.draw(iris_frequency)
```

[image]

However, when I do `using gadfly` I get an error when calling `AlgebraOfGraphics.draw()`, and it is not clear to me why.

```
using Gadfly
AoG.draw(iris_frequency)
```

> MethodError: no method matching size(::Compose.Property{Compose.FillPrimitive})
>
> Closest candidates are:
>
> size(!Matched::Union{LinearAlgebra.QR, LinearAlgebra.QRCompactWY, LinearAlgebra.QRPivoted}) at /opt/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/qr.jl:524
>
> size(!Matched::Union{LinearAlgebra.QR, LinearAlgebra.QRCompactWY, LinearAlgebra.QRPivoted}, !Matched::Integer) at /opt/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/qr.jl:523
>
> size(!Matched::Union{LinearAlgebra.Cholesky, LinearAlgebra.CholeskyPivoted}) at /opt/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/cholesky.jl:442
>
> ...
>
> axes @abstractarray.jl:89[inlined]
> combine_axes(::Compose.Property{Compose.FillPrimitive}, ::Compose.Property{Compose.FillPrimitive}, ::Compose.Property{Compose.FillPrimitive})@broadcast.jl:483
> shape(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:17
> getlabeledarray(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, ::Symbol)@processing.jl:72
> (::AlgebraOfGraphics.var"#119#121"{Tuple{Symbol, Symbol}, AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, Dict{Union{Int64, Symbol}, Any}})(::Int64)@processing.jl:100
> ntuple@ntuple.jl:19[inlined]
> mapkeys@entries.jl:75[inlined]
> (::AlgebraOfGraphics.var"#118#120"{AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, Dict{Union{Int64, Symbol}, Any}})(::Tuple{Symbol, Symbol})@processing.jl:99
> map@tuple.jl:214[inlined]
> process_mappings(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:98
> to_entry(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:115
> process(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:122
> iterate@generator.jl:47[inlined]
> collect(::Base.Generator{AlgebraOfGraphics.Layers, typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.process)})@array.jl:678
> map@abstractarray.jl:2323[inlined]
> var"#compute_axes_grid#81"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.compute_axes_grid), ::Makie.Figure, ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:70
> var"#plot!#90"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(Makie.plot!), ::Makie.Figure, ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:135
> #plot#91@layers.jl:143[inlined]
> var"#draw#92"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.draw), ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:150
> draw(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:150
> getlabeledarray(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, ::Symbol)@processing.jl:72
> (::AlgebraOfGraphics.var"#119#121"{Tuple{Symbol, Symbol}, AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, Dict{Union{Int64, Symbol}, Any}})(::Int64)@processing.jl:100
> ntuple@ntuple.jl:19[inlined]
> mapkeys@entries.jl:75[inlined]
> (::AlgebraOfGraphics.var"#118#120"{AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer, Dict{Union{Int64, Symbol}, Any}})(::Tuple{Symbol, Symbol})@processing.jl:99
> map@tuple.jl:214[inlined]
> top-level scope@Local: 7[inlined]process_mappings(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:98
> to_entry(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:115
> process(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@processing.jl:122
> iterate@generator.jl:47[inlined]
> collect(::Base.Generator{AlgebraOfGraphics.Layers, > typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.process)})@array.jl:678
> map@abstractarray.jl:2323[inlined]
> var"#compute_axes_grid#81"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.compute_axes_grid), ::Makie.Figure, ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:70
> var"#plot!#90"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(Makie.plot!), ::Makie.Figure, ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:135
> #plot#91@layers.jl:143[inlined]
> var"#draw#92"(::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}, ::typeof(AlgebraOfGraphics.draw), ::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:150
> draw(::AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer)@layers.jl:150
> top-level scope@Local: 7[inlined]

Commenting out `# using Gadfly` doesn't resolve the error, but that might be a caused by Pluto.

Pluto's live docs recognizes `AoG.draw()` as an *AlgebraOfGraphics* function, and `typeof(iris_frequency)` returns `AlgebraOfGraphics.Layer` (What you would expect.)

Does somebody have any idea how *Gadfly* can cause this error, and how I can solve it (apart from creating the plots in different notebooks.)